# Azure AD B2C - Remove the option to change e-mail during forget password flow

Tags: azure-active-directory

When I choose the 'forget password' option, I go through a flow to verify my e-mail address. Once the email is verified, I am given a screen with an option to change my email.  Why does this happen? How can I remove this step?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it in docs - [Hide the change email button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#hide-the-change-email-button)

> After the email is verified, the user can still select Change email, enter another email address, and then repeat email verification. If you'd prefer to hide the Change email button, you can modify the CSS to hide the associated HTML elements in the dialog

```css
<style type="text/css">
   .changeClaims
   {
     visibility: hidden;
   }
</style>
```

Still not sure why this option is on by default but at least there is a way to turn it off.